# PHP IDE with Spell Check

Tags: php, eclipse, netbeans, ide, aptana

I tried many IDEs on Windows OS; netbeans, eclipse, aptana but Spell Check is not working in any of them.

I want an editor which highlights(underlines) the wrong words in php file.

Comment: Did you enable spell-checking? I'm pretty sure it works.

Comment: @Bolt, about which IDE you are taking about? Please mention its Version also.

Comment: Spell checker works great in netbeans.  Its what I use.  I think it is enabled by default.

Comment: @TimWithers, I tried netbeans 7, spell check is not working in PHP code. Eg: echo 'Hello Worl';  its not highlighting wring word "Worl".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried [PhpStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/)? It has built-in spell check and other nice features.

[image: spell check at work]

I am not a PhpStorm user but I use other jetbrains products and they are all great. Highly recommended.

Comment: @sandbox: I've used both netbeans and PhpStorm for PHP projects. Netbeans is great, but for PHP I prefer PhpStorm. It was made specifically for PHP and I find it allows for a nicer PHP workflow. I recommend you give it a try!

Answer (score 1):

What about enabling spell-checking?

In Eclipse by example:
http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-enable-or-disable-spell-checking-in-ec.html

In Eclipse, you could also add the eSpell plugin:
http://www.bdaum.de/eclipse/eSpell3/

EDIT:
If what you want is to check your English spelling, in Eclipse you can use user-defined dictionaries, like shown [Here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t17453.html)

You can find dictionaries for English [Here](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Spell check is fully enabled as far as I can see, but no underlining of bad spelling in PHP files. Have tried in different types of comments, strings etc.. It works in other places like Java, JS etc...

Comment: Oh, you are talking about checking the English in your code, as I can see. Well, this is more complicated, because when programming people normally use lot of words out of the dictionary. However, you could always define your own dictionary (or copy an existing one) and use it

Comment: How to define english dictionary in eclipse or netbeans?

Comment: @sandbox I edited the answer to add the English checking information using user-defined dictionaries in Eclipse